Textbook proving distance formula on a product manifold
I am looking for a reference that proves the formula shown in this question, saying that the distance function $d$ of a product manifold $M \times N$ is giving by the following equation, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the distance functions of the manifolds $M$ and $N$ :
$$d \, ((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=\sqrt{d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2}$$
I have checked different books of topology:

Michel Marie Deza and Elena Deza, Encyclopedia of Distances
John M. Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds
Manfredo P. do Carmo, Riemannian Geometry
Gregory L. Naber, Topology, Geometry and Gauge fields: Foundations

But none of them proposes the derivation of this exact formula.

That's a definition, not a theorem.  Of course, you need to confirm that this is a valid distance function (given that $d_1,d_2$ are ).

Thanks, but why is this definition common? Why using the Euclidean distance rather than $L^\infty$ norm for instance?

One geometric motivation for defining a "Pythagorean" product metric is so a product of Euclidean spaces is a Euclidean space. Inversely, the usual definition of a product of Riemannian manifolds gives a metric satisfying the "Pythagorean theorem" as stated. <> In analysis and topology, however, other metrics may be equivalent (define the same topology) and formally simpler to work with; in that context they're a "better" choice. <> Is that what you're asking?

@AndrewD.Hwang yes, especially the part where you say that "the usual definition of a product of Riemannian manifolds gives a metric satisfying the "Pythagorean theorem" as stated".

This generalized the usual Euclidesn distance in the plane.
